# mssql compare two tables and only return non identical columns

Tags: sql-server, datatables, compare

I would like to know if two tables 'table1' and 'table2' are identical.
I know I could compare every column of both tables in the 'where'-clause
So this would basically show me every Row that is identical.

But what I want to know is which columns are identical. So I think it would be easy to just transpone the tables and compare the results as mentioned before. Column names and order in the tables are both identical as already given.
I made also an example Input and Output scenario:

-------Input---------------
table1

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 23 | 45 |
| 2 | 12 | 21 | 43 |
| 3 | 12 | 22 | 43 |
| 4 | 10 | 12 | 41 |
| 5 | 11 | 23 | 44 |
| 6 | 13 | 25 | 43 |

table2

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 20 | 45 |
| 2 | 12 | 0 | 43 |
| 3 | 12 | 22 | 43 |
| 4 | 10 | 30 | 41 |
| 5 | 11 | 23 | 44 |
| 6 | 13 |  | 43 |

----------Output----------------

result

| col2 |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 0 |
| 22 |
| 30 |
| 23 |
|  |

OR result

| ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col2 | 20 | 0 | 22 | 30 | 23 |  |

OR result

| col2 |
| --- |

OR result

| table1.col2 | table2.col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 20 |
| 21 | 0 |
| 22 | 22 |
| 12 | 30 |
| 23 | 23 |
| 25 |  |

OR similar.....
The values of the non identical columns dont matter I just need the column name, but I wouldnt care if values would come along with it. I hope its not too diffcult.

Comment: A result set can't include different columns per row of course, your desired results only feature the column you already know to have differences so what if table1 had a different value for col1?

Comment: Please check your example - it doen't match the described expected result. You wrote "only identical columns" but you expect an output of Col2 with value 20 - which is only included in the second table and with this Col2 is not identical in both tables.

Comment: I want to know the columns in which every value correspond with every value of the other column, thats what I call identical columns. If I know the not identical I of course also know the identical ones, so its the same I dont care which one of them. Also it doesnt matter how the column will be displayed whether with or without values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consifering you really want to receive only the identical columns, you might want to try an approach using unpivot. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(
   id int
  ,col1 int
  ,col2 int
  ,col3 int
);

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES
 (1,14,23,45)
,(2,12,21,43)
,(3,12,22,43)
,(4,10,12,41)
,(5,11,23,44)
,(6,13,25,43);

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(
   id int
  ,col1 int
  ,col2 int
  ,col3 int
);

INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES
 (1,14,20,45)
,(2,12,0,43)
,(3,12,22,43)
,(4,10,30,41)
,(5,11,23,44)
,(6,13,NULL,43);

WITH cte1 AS(
  SELECT id, col, val
    FROM (SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM @t1) p
  UNPIVOT
    (val FOR col IN (col1, col2, col3)) as unpvt
),
cte2 AS(
  SELECT id, col, val
    FROM (SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM @t2) p
  UNPIVOT
    (val FOR col IN (col1, col2, col3)) as unpvt
)
SELECT DISTINCT c1.id, c1.col, c1.val
  FROM cte1 c1
  INNER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c2.id = c1.id AND c2.col = c1.col AND c2.val = c1.val
  ORDER BY 1, 2
```